# How can I stream remote epub in android app

Tags: android, remote-access, remote-server, epub

I want my application to stream / read `ePub` from remote and display it to readers. The `ePub` wont be saved on client.

Is it possible to stream remote `ePub`?

Searched google on this but didn't get any relevant.
If anyone tried this please help me out!
An Yes or No will be appreciated if with source. Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to save epubs on client then you can do Web Application, check 
https://github.com/readium/readium-js.

If you have website which can be used to read epub you can just wrap-up access to this website in Android app and you will achieve desired result.